# Sum of counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count all the cells of columnA and columnB that are not null and has a value. I am getting the counts separately in two queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users where columnA IS NOT NULL AND columnA <>''
```

This query returns value = 7.
And for columnB, I do the same and get value 5 by

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users where columnB IS NOT NULL AND columnA <>''
```

But how can I query both of the columns at the same time and return the sum of the counts that is 12?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(columnA IS NOT NULL AND columnA <>'') + SUM(columnB IS NOT NULL AND columnB <>'')
FROM users
```

or:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(columnA, '') <>'') + SUM(COALESCE(columnB, '') <>'')
FROM users
```

Comment: Thanks, I really loved the second option. It looks clean and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Find count and add them - use case when to count on some condition

```
 SELECT COUNT(case when columnA IS NOT NULL AND columnA <>'' then 1 end) +
 COUNT(case when columnB IS NOT NULL AND columnB <>'' then 1 end) FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
select suma, sumb, suma+sumb sumtotal from (
 select sum(case when colA>'' then 1 end) suma,
        sum(case when colB>'' then 1 end) sumb from users ) u
```

Since we are testing for `colA>''` the condition `IS NOT NULL` will always be fulfilled and does not need to be tested for.